# stored procedure with isnull(expression, replacement) return nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, isnull

I  have a stored procedure that accepts parameter and return tuple with matching values. If no parameter is passed, then return every tuple in the table

```
create procedure getScore
(
    @clinicCode varchar = null,
)
as
begin
    select * from myTable
    where ClinicCode = isnull(@clinicCode, ClinicCode)
end
```

so I executte it

```
exec getScore
exec getScore 'PSH'
```

both of them return no tuple.
    I did try **select * from myTable**, and they returns all tuples. Not sure why the statement from ... **isnull(expression, replacement)** get messed up

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the declaration of

```
@clinicCode varchar = null,
```

to the actual size you require.

So something like

```
@clinicCode varchar(50) = null,
```

The reason for this is that

```
@clinicCode varchar
```

is the same as

```
@clinicCode varchar(1)
```

Which then casts your field `isnull(@clinicCode, ClinicCode)` to only the first letter of `ClinicCode`

Have a look at this example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73808/3)